# How do I install bitnami Wordpress?

Tags: software-installation, wordpress, bitnami

How do I install Bitnami Wordpress after downloading it?

I was a Windows User, and installing the Wordpress installer on Xampp is easy, just double click the installer and next until finished.

Comment: I believe the downloaded file has a `.run` extension? Open a terminal and `cd` to the `Downloads` file. Then do `chmod +x [filename.run]` to make it executable. Finally, run the file by entering `[filename.run]`. (Replace [filename.run] with the actual name of the file.)

Answer (score 1):

The Bitnami Wordpress Linux Installer is pretty much plug-and-play (depending on how you do it).

If you're installing from your bare OS, all you need to do is [grab the install runfile from the download site](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress) and then do the following:

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `cd Downloads` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Find the filename for the install file (at the time of writing, `bitnami-wordpress-4.7.3-0-linux-x64-installer.run`). For all steps below, I will be assuming the filename is `bitnami-wordpress.run`. Change this accordingly.
4. Run the following command to start the install process:

   ```
   chmod +x bitnami-wordpress.run && ./bitnami-wordpress.run
   ```
5. If the installer asks for root permission, run the following command instead (if needed):

   ```
   sudo ./bitnami-wordpress.run
   ```

Alternatively, I would personally recommend you use the [Docker setup](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress) for Bitnami Wordpress. How to is much simpler:

1. Install [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/) and [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/), and run `sudo apt install curl`.
2. Make a folder or similar to store the config file for Bitnami Wordpress. I personally would recommend `Bitnami-WP` in your home folder.
3. `cd` to the folder where you want the configs to go.
4. Run these commands:

   ```
   curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress/master/docker-compose.yml
   docker-compose up
   ```

Whenever you are done, just `cd` back to wherever the compose file exists, and run `docker-compose down` to shut down the install.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your downloaded file to something easy like `bitnami.run`, once you have done this, open the terminal on your computer and type:

```
cd Downloads
```

and press enter, once that is done, look for your Wordpress download and type

```
sudo ./bitnami.run
```

once that is done, you will be asked to put your password

> enter your password and press enter

once that is done, your Wordpress installation will begin.